# Does iOS 17 include an API akin to the Android Context Hub Runtime Environment, capable of executing system applications on low-power processors?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, react-native, dart

Does iOS 17 include an API akin to the Android Context Hub Runtime Environment, capable of executing system applications on low-power processors?

I sought to expand my knowledge, so I began studying Linux and its distributions, including mobile Linux, through Cloud Guru. During this process, I discovered Android CHRE.

Comment: Not as such, because ios only runs on Apple hardware so there is no need to support auxiliary processors. Developers can help iOS manage power use by directing their workloads to the efficiency cores via [qos](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=vk3m204o)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.